# Какой есть более оптимальный способ удалить из строки символы пунктуации?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста более оптимальный на ваш взгляд удалить из строки все символы пунктуации, в том числе возможно без использования метода replaceAll и regex

```
String strBefore = "heLLo, privEt!23,_ %@()\".;@ kl \n wow";

String strAfter1 = strBefore.replaceAll("\\W|[0-9]|[_]", "");
String strAfter2 = strBefore.replaceAll("[^a-z^A-Z]", "");
```

Comment: Оптимальный в плане чего? Чем вас регулярки не устраивают?

Comment: Можно использовать регулярку `"\\p{Punct}"`. Описана в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Матчит любой из символов `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~` и символ `

Comment: @LEQADA Оптимальный - я подразумеваю простоту понятия и читаемость. Мои скудные познания просто не позволяют оценить написанный код и я подозреваю, что возможно написал велосипед и уже существует какой либо метод, или конструкция регулярки для подобной цели

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если без регулярных выражений, вот три варианта на вскидку:

Вариант 1:

```
public static String removePunct(String str) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(c) || Character.isDigit(c) || Character.isSpaceChar(c)) {
            result.append(c);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
private static final String PUNCT = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~";

public static String removePunct2(String str) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (PUNCT.indexOf(c) < 0) {
            result.append(c);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Вариант 3:

```
private static final Set<Character> PUNCT_SET = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
        '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', '\'', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-',
        '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^',
        '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~'
));

public static String removePunct3(String str) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (!PUNCT_SET.contains(Character.valueOf(c))) {
            result.append(c);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: вот вы заморочились) Вообще наверное еще множество способов можно придумать и как сказал автор свыше, действительно - все это велосипеды, применимые лишь, на мой взгляд, в исключительных или нестандартных ситуациях. Спасибо

Answer (score 7):

Без использования регулярного выражения как раз и будет изобретение велосипеда.

Используйте `\pP`:

```
String s = "heLLo, privEt!23,_ %@()\".;@ kl \n wow";
System.out.println("ДО:\n" + s + "\n==============");
System.out.println("ПОСЛЕ:\n" + s.replaceAll("\\pP", ""));
```

[Демо](http://ideone.com/SAZkqe) (результат: `heLLo privEt23  kl \n wow`)

Для удаления пунктуации и пробелов, рекомендую символьный класс `[\pP\s]`

```
System.out.println("ПОСЛЕ:\n" + s.replaceAll("(?U)[\\pP\\s]", ""));
```

Если указан модификатор `(?U)`, классы находят все символы Юникода, которым они соответствуют (доступен начиная с Java 7).

Comment: Благодарю, но требуется в т.ч. с удалением пробелов и переходом на новые строки, \\p{Punct} - в этом плане более подходящий паттерн (или класс, как правильнее @Alexandr Petrov ?) Хочу правда спросить - а что это за конструкция **\pP**  и как она работает, в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) не нашел. Не там искал возможно правда

Comment: `\p{Punct}` и `\pP` - синонимы. Это класс категории Юникода (Unicode category class). Если надо удалить вместе с пробелами, используйте символьный класс `[\pP\s]`. Возможно,  вместе с модификатором `(?U)`: `"(?U)[\\pP\\s]"` ([тут подробнее о `(?U)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) - если указан, классы находят все символы Юникода, которым они соответствуют).

Comment: Благодарю, про синонимы не знал, выглядит чутка, но компактнее.